# angularjs filter a table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

```
<tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="y in Summary">
            <td>{{y.ID}}</td>                       
            <td>{{y.submitTime}}</td>
            <td>{{y.timeTaken}}</td>
            <td>{{y.description}}</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to filter the values when user selects a checkbox-exclude Non-members.

So the Non member array has IDs of users.

```
$scope.Nonmember=["521","234","456", etc]
```

So when the user selects the checkbox I want to remove the rows which have IDs in nonmember . Can a filter be used for searching through the whole array ?..
or ng-show/hide/if can be used??

Comment: I suggest that you identify which records are members in advance that way your filter just needs to work on your checkbox = true and member =true

Comment: there's the problem, the nonmember array is dynamic , the values are retrieved from ajax calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A filter can do.

For example:

```
angular
    .module( ... )
    .filter( 'excludeNonMembers', function(){
        return filterMembers;
    } );

function filterMembers( summary, nm, exclude ){
    if(!exclude) return summary;
    if( !nm || nm.length == 0 ) return summary;
    return summary.filter( function( i ){
        return nm.indexOf( i.ID ) == -1;
    } );
}
```

In your html:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="y in summary | filter:excludeNonMembers:Nonmember:exclude">
```

The `$scope.exclude` variable is a boolean that you toggle somewhere to apply the filter.

Comment: This look like exactly what i needed !